Why can't I simply make one float equal to another in my Struct?
struct myStruct {
        float start;        
        float newStart;
        newStart = start;
}

Why am I getting this error for newStart?

this declaration has no storage class or type

specifier

you can't just put code in a class.  code goes into functions.  Sounds like you could use a good C++ book

Make a constructor and set the values of your floats there.

Fun fact: struct myStruct { float start=0; float newStart=start; } would actually work -- members are initialized top to bottom.

Struct needs to end with a semicolon. start hasn’t been assigned a value so don’t expect you can assign it to newStart. Anyway you can’t put an assignment there!

"A house has a front door and a back door. Make the front door of the house the same size as the back door." Do it when, and for which house?

Do you mean that these two values should always be equal to each other? If so, then why should they be separate values?

You can do it with constructors:
struct myStruct {
   float start;
   float newStart;

   myStruct(float s, float ns) : start(s), newStart(ns) {}
   myStruct(float s) : myStruct(s, s) {}
};

After that you can use either constructor to initialize new instances:
myStruct ms_1{4, 7};
assert(ms_1.start == 4 && ms_1.newStart == 7); 
myStruct ms_2{3};
assert(ms_2.start == 3 && ms_2.newStart == 3); 


If you want the change of one member to cause the change of another one, you likely want a union. Expressions that are not parts of definitions are not allowed outside functions.
struct myStruct {
    union {
        float start;        
        float newStart;
    }
};

If you only want to make them equally initialized, then
struct myStruct {
    float start = 0;        
    float newStart = start;
};

